# Sorting Array by Key (Key is a string)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a simple Array. The goal is, to sort them ascending by the key.

```
$someUnsortedArray = array("140/142" => "FirstValue", "118/120" => "SecondValue", "122/124" => "ThirdValue", "40/42" => "FourthValue");

ksort($someUnsortedArray);
```

**My Output:**

```
array (size=4)  
  '118/120' => string 'SecondValue' 
  '122/124' => string 'ThirdValue'  
  '140/142' => string 'FirstValue'   
  '40/42' => string 'FourthValue'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
array (size=4)  
'40/42' => string 'FourthValue'  
'118/120' => string 'SecondValue'   
'122/124' => string 'ThirdValue'  
'140/142' => string 'FirstValue'
```

What's the function in php I am searching for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `uksort()` in this case:

```
$someUnsortedArray = array("140/142" => "FirstValue", "118/120" => "SecondValue", "122/124" => "ThirdValue", "40/42" => "FourthValue");

uksort($someUnsortedArray, function($a, $b){
    $a = str_replace('/', '', $a);
    $b = str_replace('/', '', $b);
    return $a - $b;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($someUnsortedArray);
```

Comment: In the theory it would work.. But is there any solution without replacing the "/" without nothing?

Comment: @Tyralcori you need to sort it in custom since you won't get the desired values if they are going to be compared as strings

Comment: @Tyralcori if you do not want a replace you could explode it

Comment: At least, that's my solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tyralcori glad this helped by the way, barry's answer is much good, you could also pick that one

Answer (score 2):

Checking php manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Use `ksort()` with `SORT_NUMERIC` flag.

```
$someUnsortedArray = array("140/142" => "FirstValue", "118/120" => "SecondValue", "122/124" => "ThirdValue", "40/42" => "FourthValue");
ksort($someUnsortedArray, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($someUnsortedArray);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8tgnRA)

Comment: what about SORT_NUMERIC

Comment: "40/42" or "118/120" aren't numeric values, they are string.

Comment: My bad, it works indeed. If you edit your answer I'll cancel my downvote. (Can't now)

Comment: Sidenote: 

As you can see this answer has a negative score, but don't downvote this answer anymore as this is already correct. +1

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can also make use of the natural order string compare function to compare the keys

```
function sortKey($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a, $b);
}

uksort($someUnsortedArray,"sortKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `uksort` and pass the function a custom function/method that will do the right conversion based on your needs.

Here is the PHP manual page for he function `uksort`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Answer (score 0):

The result *is* the expected behaviour, because if you sort Strings in alphanumerical order 1* is always before 4*.

If you want to have it sorted by number you'll have to split your string, convert the elements to number and sort them by number.

Implementation depends on what you want to achieve. Just a list of the Keys? Then you could iterate in an foreach loop adressing the keys for example.

There won't be an "out-of-the-box" PHP Function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$someUnsortedArray = array("5/142" => "FirstValue", "118/120" => "SecondValue", "122/124" => "ThirdValue", "40/42" => "FourthValue");

uksort($someUnsortedArray, function($a, $b) {
    // to avoid manipulating them as a string ....      
    return ((float)$a)-((float)$b);
});
var_dump($someUnsortedArray);
```